# Faster way to get single cell value from Dataframe (using just transformation)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have the following code where I want to get Dataframe dfDateFiltered from dfBackendInfo containing all rows with RowCreationTime greater than timestamp "latestRowCreationTime"

```
val latestRowCreationTime = dfVersion.agg(max("BackendRowCreationTime")).first.getTimestamp(0)
val dfDateFiltered = dfBackendInfo.filter($"RowCreationTime" > latestRowCreationTime)
```

The problem I see is that the first line adds a job in Databricks cluster making it slower.
Is there anyway if I could use a better way to filter (for ex. just using transformation instead of action)?

Below are the schemas of the 2 Dataframes:

```
case class Version(BuildVersion:String,
                   MainVersion:String,
                   Hotfix:String,
                   BackendRowCreationTime:Timestamp)
                   
case class BackendInfo(SerialNumber:Integer,
                       NumberOfClients:Long,
                       BuildVersion:String,
                       MainVersion:String,
                       Hotfix:String,
                       RowCreationTime:Timestamp)
```

Comment: Can you add the schema of the two dataframes?

Comment: Please see the above edited question.

Comment: Maybe if you can join the two datasets by one of the fields you could include the  filter as a second condition of the join to perform the filter in one action. As long as you need to query the first dataset to extract a value you will need two actions, if you want to work with two datasets in one action you must join the two DSs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have posted below the working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked:

```
val dfLatestRowCreationTime1 = dfVersion.agg(max($"BackendRowCreationTime").as("BackendRowCreationTime")).limit(1)
val latestRowCreationTime = dfLatestRowCreationTime1.withColumn("BackendRowCreationTime", when($"BackendRowCreationTime".isNull, DefaultTime))
val dfDateFiltered = dfBackendInfo.join(latestRowCreationTime, dfBackendInfo.col("RowCreationTime").gt(latestRowCreationTime.col("BackendRowCreationTime")))
```